# Scala compiler error due to constructor parameter (property) having same name in both base and derived class and used in derived method

Tags: scala, constructor

Short of renaming the constructor parameter in the primary constructor of class `B`, what change can I make to the following code (without changing its function) so that Scala will compile it successfully?

Example:

```
class A(var a: Int)
class B(a: Int) extends A(a) {
  def inc(value: Int) { this.a += value }
}
```

Error:

```
$ scala construct.scala
construct.scala:3: error: reassignment to val
  def inc(value: Int) { this.a += value }
                               ^
one error found
```

I raised this question in an [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1889454/in-scala-how-do-you-define-a-local-parameter-in-the-primary-constructor-of-a-cla/1890211#1890211) to my previous question, ["In Scala, how do you define a local parameter in the primary constructor of a class?"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1889454/in-scala-how-do-you-define-a-local-parameter-in-the-primary-constructor-of-a-cla/1890211#1890211).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
class A(var a: Int)
class B(a: Int) extends A(a) {
  def inc(value: Int) { (this: A).a += value }
}
```

Comment: Nice!  The type cast `(this: A)` is new to me!

Comment: Me, too.  Daniel Sobral introduced me to it recently. http://stackoverflow.com/users/53013/daniel

Comment: Note that this is a type-safe upcast, unlike (this.asInstanceOf[A]).a, which would have also compiled.

Comment: Cool. Now I know a little further (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1889454/in-scala-how-do-you-define-a-local-parameter-in-the-primary-constructor-of-a-cla).

Comment: Note: `(this: A)` is technically referred to as "type ascription" (http://davetron5000.github.com/scala-style/types/ascription.html).

Answer (score 1):

Another alternative:

```
class A(var a: Int)
class B(a: Int) extends A(a) {
  self: A => 
  def inc(value: Int) { self.a += value }
}
```

This might work better for more extensive cases, as you can use `self` (or whatever other name you choose) throughout the body of the function.

Comment: This compiles, but is not correct.
val x = new B(1); x.inc(5); println(x.a) // == 1

Comment: Daniel, I guess you mistaken a little bit: you are making an anonymous function (A) => Unit in `inc` and don't return it, as inc's return type is Unit. So no increment happens. Obviously, `self: A =>` should be after class B's opening brace.

Comment: You are both correct, my mistake. I have moved the `self: A =>` statement to the proper place.